# Count number of sentence in a java string

Tags: java, string

Hi i want to count number of sentences in a string so far i am using this:

```
int count = str.split("[!?.:]+").length;
```

But my string includes "." in names and in between words also for example

"He name is Walton D.C. and he just completed his B.Tech last year."

Now using above line as example count will return 4 sentences but there is only one.

So how to deal with these situations?

Comment: How must it understand the difference between these two options?

Comment: Chosen language is English only

Comment: That's what i am thinking how to differentiate

Comment: Problem is that you even can't be sure that it's only single characters before the dots, e.g. `etc.` etc. ;) - I'd say you'd be best off looking for some library that understands the meaning of the text and thus can correctly "guess" which dots end a sentence (depends on the text though, some "sentences" are even hard for humans). The only other thing I can think of would be to use a list of known abbreviations but that will probably never be complete and can grow quite a lot.

Comment: Yes that is also a problem

Comment: [JAVA 8 can determine Sentence Boundaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/sentence.html)

Comment: Is there a library i am using this in android development using java

Comment: split("\.\s[A-Z\n]")

Comment: Issue is i am using java for android and android development doesn't support java 8

Comment: @SahilShokeen It seems Java 7 also has `BreakIterators`

Comment: Thanks i will have a look at them

Comment: Just use [OpenNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853112/counting-sentence-in-text-file-using-java?rq=1), probably this is the best solution.

Comment: Here's an official link to [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BreakIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html), and detect different kinds of [text boundaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/boundaryintro.html)

In your case Sentences:

```
private static void markBoundaries(String target, BreakIterator iterator) {
    StringBuffer markers = new StringBuffer();
    markers.setLength(target.length() + 1);
    for (int k = 0; k < markers.length(); k++) {
        markers.setCharAt(k, ' ');
    }
    int count = 0;
    iterator.setText(target);
    int boundary = iterator.first();
    while (boundary != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        markers.setCharAt(boundary, '^');
        ++count;
        boundary = iterator.next();
    }
    System.out.println(target);
    System.out.println(markers);
    System.out.println("Number of Boundaries: " + count);
    System.out.println("Number of Sentences: " + (count-1));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale currentLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
    BreakIterator sentenceIterator
            = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(currentLocale);
    String someText = "He name is Walton D.C. and he just completed his B.Tech last year.";
    markBoundaries(someText, sentenceIterator);
    someText = "This order was placed for QT3000! MK?";
    markBoundaries(someText, sentenceIterator);

}
```

The output will be:

```
He name is Walton D.C. and he just completed his B.Tech last year.
^                                                                 ^
Number of Boundaries: 2
Number of Sentences: 1
This order was placed for QT3000! MK?
^                                 ^  ^
Number of Boundaries: 3
Number of Sentences: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be that in case of dots, you can check if u have a space and a capital letter after it.

**"[dot][space][capital letter]"**

That will be an assurance for the sentence for sure

Updating the code for the same:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! MK? \n Thats amazing. \n But I am not sure.";
  String pattern = "([.!?])([\\s\\n])([A-Z]*)";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  int count=0;
  while (m.find( )) {
      count++;
  }
  count++; //for the last line, which will not get included here.
  System.out.println("COUNT=="+count);
}
```

Comment: "B.Tech" will not satisfy your condition

Comment: @Simion `B.Tech` would be not recognized as a sentence delimiter (that's what Yashi is going at) but if I understand the OP correctly it could also be `B. Tech` which would be a false positive.

Comment: it will. there is no space in B.T i think. shortcuts don't have space logically.

Comment: Please note that your example ("This order was placed for QT3000! MK?") would be too easy. As the OP stated the problem is not finding sentence delimiters but distinguishing them from abbreviations etc. in (as I assume arbitrary) English text. Thus you'd need to prove the solution using a _hard_ test case (or even multiple test cases).

Comment: Leave the example. My focus is on the logic. The logic goes with all test cases.

Comment: how it will display number of sentences?

Comment: int count = 0;  
        while(m.find()) {
            count++;
        }       //for count of sentences @SahilShokeen

Comment: @SahilShokeen do u think the answer solves your problem?

Comment: I have a large string comprising of paragraphs so this method is not working

Comment: for that i guess you can use 1 more condition of [DELIMITERS][NEXT LINE]. that would solve that problem. Will edit my code for that.

Comment: @SahilShokeen i have edited the code for paragraphs as well. For more variations, you can try the different regex. All cases will surely get covered if working on regex.

Answer (score 1):

easy Way to do

public class CountLines {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s="Find the number Sentence";
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)==' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    count=count+1;
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One solution cane be to skip dots if you have one or more UPERCASE letters before it. In this case names(if they are in upercase). Implementing this you will have only one sentence.

Another solution: improving one answer here could be: [lowercase]([dot] or [?] or [!])[space][uppercase]

But like i said, if there are no exact rules, it will be almost impossible.

Comment: But its not compulsory there will be uppercase letters before "." for example "b.tech" or "etc."

Comment: I wrote in paranthesis. You should define some restrictions, some rules - all letters used for names to be in Uppercase(or something like this). Otherwise even a human will not be possible to separate one sentence from another.